# How to install packages when Pip installation wont work

Tags: python, pip, installation

I am trying to install packages-`openpyxl`,`textwrap`,`datetime` etc. But it is showing error after `'Connecting ...'`
I have tried following methods-

1. `pip install` package (this worked for some of the packages like `pywin32`)
2. unchecking and checking `proxy server box`
3. I have tried downloading `.tar.gz` files and then installing them
   using (this worked for `xlrd`,`xlsxwriter`)

`pip install file.tar.gz`

4. Tried following commands-

`pip install --proxy=user:pass@server:port openpyxl`

`pip install --proxy domain\user:password@proxyaddress:port openpyxl`

I have been trying to find solutions to this for a while now but could not find any other solution to install rest of the packages which are `openpyxl`,`Jinja2`,`textwrap` and `datetime`. Is there any other way to get this done?

Comment: what's the error you get exacty ?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to do this on your professional box and they are forbidding connections to PyPI? You can always download the archive by hand and do a `python setup.py install` manually (after extracting the archive, of course).

Comment: @PRMoureu something like this

`Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000049701D0>, 'Connection to pypi
.anaconda.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /pypi/simple/whois/`

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher  I have tried that as well and it showed error something like- File could not found.
However, I have already installed some packages from PyPI. So I can not be sure if the actual problem is related to this.

Comment: Indeed, seems like you can't connect to anaconda. Professional workstation?

Comment: Wish [this link](https://coderwall.com/p/lykptw/tell-pip-to-use-a-mirror) can help you. Try to use a mirror.

Comment: @BenLee Thanks. I will let you know if this works for me.